# Neural Networks Model Predictions on Same Sample

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, denoising-autoencoder

I have built a tensorflow model to reconstruct the given input data sample by using an Autoencoder to predict the Missingness in the sample. However I do not have enough data sample where i don't have missingness in the samples. Hence I tried to check the model predictions with the mean imputed values where the NAN values are present.

However this analysis is not helping me well.

Hence, I thought to predict the same sample multiple times to understand how the model is predicting so that I can understand how the model is behaving in predicting the value where the NAN is present. I would then like to plot a distribution to understand the range of values that my model is trying to predict. However, I am getting the same exact predictions when I tried to predict the sample. May I know why it is happening like that?